# Binding Data table to a Grid View in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, datatable

I have a grid view as follows:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblModifiedFilesMessage" runat="server" />
       <asp:GridView ID="gvPopUpModifiedFiles" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0"runat="server">
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFileSelect" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FileName" DataField="FileName" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOk" Text="OK" runat="server"
            Font-Bold="true" onclick="btnOk_Click" /><br />
    </div>
```

I am trying to bind the data for this grid view in a method as follows:

```
private void PopUpModifiedFiles(List<ProjectFile> ModifiedFiles)
{
    this.lblModifiedFilesMessage.Text = "Below files are modified in the Source Server and will be archived with latest version. Please select any files if they are to be retained with older version in archive";
    DataTable dtModifiedFiles = new DataTable();
    dtModifiedFiles.Columns.Add("FileName");
    foreach (ProjectFile modifiedFile in ModifiedFiles)
    {
        DataRow drFileName = dtModifiedFiles.NewRow();
        drFileName["FileName"] = modifiedFile.FileName;
        dtModifiedFiles.Rows.Add(drFileName);
    }
    gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataSource = dtModifiedFiles;
    gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataBind();

}
```

Here while assigning the data table to the grid view It is showing me an error as does not contain definition for `gvPopUpModifiedFiles`. Do I need to write any method for this gvPopUpModifiedFiles?

How to assign the values?

Answer (score 0):

For bind the grid you must set DataTable on the property **DataSource** and call the method [**DataBind**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataSource = dtModifiedFiles;
gvPopUpModifiedFiles.DataBind();
```

The problem could be the attribute on directive Page, properties CodeBehind Inherits. You can control in this way

File aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.Index" %>
```

File CS:

```
namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The file Index.aspx.cs in CodeBehind must exists and Inherits attribute must be the fullname's class in CS

Comment: It is telling that gvPopUpModifiedFiles does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Can you post all page?

Comment: Post also the exception, please

Comment: when I am writing this gvPopUpModifiedFiles it is marked with red line as it does not exist in the current context

Comment: Some time its problem of the IDE did you try restarting the VS ?

Comment: Do you have check the  CodeFile and Inherits properties (directive Page) on the file aspx?

Comment: I inherited that in my page at the 1st time itself. still the same error

Comment: @kartikasi - You are adding this method in the code behinf file right?